# Corona SDK ScrollView scrolled amount to trigger element

Tags: function, lua, scrollview, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I have a "logic" type of question and I am using Corona SDK.

I am using the ScrollView widget and was wondering if I could create a function or something to set a "y" amount that when scrolled to or past triggers an element(a top navigational bar) to fade in or out depending on the direction of scroll.

**Take my example:**

You have your ScrollView and you scroll down(y) 30px. The element is at `alpha = 0` and starts fading in and when you get to 40px it's `alpha = 1`. Same for scrolling up but the opposite, `alpha = 1` at 40px and `alpha = 0` at 30px.

It would be nice if I could have the element(a top navigational bar) fade in or out as you scroll to set "y" amount from either direction and not all at once. So if you only scroll 35px the element is at `alpha = 5`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was taken from the Corona SDK example:

```
local widget = require( "widget" )

-- ScrollView listener
local function scrollListener( event )

    local phase = event.phase
    if ( phase == "began" ) then print( "Scroll view was touched" )
    elseif ( phase == "moved" ) then print( "Scroll view was moved" )
    elseif ( phase == "ended" ) then print( "Scroll view was released" )
    end

    -- In the event a scroll limit is reached...
    if ( event.limitReached ) then
        if ( event.direction == "up" ) then print( "Reached top limit" )
        elseif ( event.direction == "down" ) then print( "Reached bottom limit" )
        elseif ( event.direction == "left" ) then print( "Reached left limit" )
        elseif ( event.direction == "right" ) then print( "Reached right limit" )
        end
    end

    return true
end

-- Create the widget
local scrollView = widget.newScrollView
{
    top = 100,
    left = 10,
    width = 300,
    height = 400,
    scrollWidth = 600,
    scrollHeight = 800,
    listener = scrollListener
}

-- Create a image and insert it into the scroll view
local background = display.newRect(160, 240, 320, 480)-- display.newImageRect( "assets/scrollimage.png", 768, 1024 )
background:setFillColor(1, 0, 0)
scrollView:insert( background )
```

you can see the scrollview widget has events for reaching it's limits among others.

```
local widget = require( "widget" )

-- ScrollView listener
local function scrollListener( event )
    if event.phase == "moved" then
        local x, y = event.target:getContentPosition()
        if y > 40 then 
            print("****")
        end 
    end 
    return true
end
```

Here's a simplified example. Here I used :getContentPosition() which returns both the x and y position of the scrollview

As you scroll down the scrollview content is moving up, the y position will be negative. For a pull to refresh you might look for a positive number, the scrollview is pulled down below the top edge of it's container. For finding when content in the scrollview is getting near the top of the scrollview container you'd look for negative numbers.

Here is an example that defines some way points at 0, -40, and -80 pixels. It prints the index of the way point when a new way point is reached.

```
local waypoints = {0, -40, -80}
local currentWayPoint = 0

-- ScrollView listener
local function scrollListener( event )
   if event.phase == "moved" then
        local x, y = event.target:getContentPosition()
        local newWayPoint = -1
        for i = 1, #waypoints do 
            local waypoint = waypoints[i]
            -- print(waypoint, y, i)
            if waypoint > y then
                newWayPoint = i
            end 
        end 
        if newWayPoint ~= currentWayPoint then 
            currentWayPoint = newWayPoint
            print( currentWayPoint )
        end 
    end 
    return true
end
```

Here the terminal should show the -1 if you drag down, and then 1, 2, and 3 as you drag up past each of the way point values, which are every 40 pixels. You could add an if statement to check if the waypoint value changes, then do something.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work with "if y > 40 then".
It only seems to work with "if y < 40 then" but its still not a perfect solution...It doesn't matter what number you put it still goes right aways.

Comment: @benlevywebdesign yeah I tried it too. Same thing you did and it is not perfect.

Comment: It is buggy in terms of corona limitations but other wise it works kinda well!

Comment: I noticed a delay between starting a drag and the first scrollview position events showing up in the terminal. Not sure what causes this.